# Help me with these meta questions

Tags: paradox

I’ve been thinking about these questions and I wonder what multiple people would write if they can do so in a paragraph or two.

> Question 1 : **What is the answer to this question?**
>
> ---
>
> Question 2 : **Is the answer to this question no?**

Comment: 1: Whatever you want to say; 2: Of course not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *could* answer in a paragraph or two, but that's not necessary.

What is the answer to this question?

> "This sentence is the answer to that question."

Is the answer to this question no?

> "Nope."

Comment: I probably would have said, "What?" for the answer to the first one. I like your answer for the second!

Answer (score 1):

My tuppence:

Question 1:

> What is the question?

Question 2:

> Maybe